How to apply a promo code to an in-app subscription purchase in Android?
I am working on an Android app using Android Studio and I have integrated in-app purchases. I have successfully created a subscription ID through the Google Play Console, and I am able to retrieve SKU details, including the price, for this subscription.
Here is the flow I am aiming for:
I created a subscription with an initial price of $200.
I have designed an interface where users can enter a promo code.
When a valid promo code is entered, the price should be reduced by 50%, so the user is charged $100 instead of $200 for the first payment cycle.
The subscription should be auto-renewed at the original price of $200 for subsequent cycles.
I would like some guidance on how to implement the promo code functional within the in-app purchase flow. Specifically, I need to know:
1)How to validate and apply the promo code to adjust the price of the subscription.
2)How to ensure the subscription renews at the original price after the initial discounted period.
Here is what I have done so far:
*I have integrated the in-app purchase API.
*I can retrieve SKU details, including price, for the subscription.
*Also make payment successfully without applying promo code.
Could anyone provide a detailed example or point me towards the relevant documentation or resources to achieve this?
I have successfully integrated the in-app purchase API in my Android app and can retrieve SKU details, including the price for my subscription. I created a user interface where users can enter a promo code. I expected that upon entering a valid promo code, the price of the subscription would be reduced accordingly for the first billing cycle, and the original price would apply for subsequent renewals. However, I am unsure how to validate and apply the promo code to adjust the subscription price dynamically.
Other suggestions also appreciated instead of InApp purchase subscription things.

Is there any update regarding this?

Hi @kk4 not any clue regarding this I have also tried in  play console community. check  link
